# Change text of local notification in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, localnotification

I developp an application for student. He can create his timetable.
I tried to create a notification how summarize the next day. So I need to change the text notification, how can I do that?

Another example, the student can write his homework. One day before to return the homework, notify him.

I'have already tried to do a simple notification, but the text of the notification is static.

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()                    
content.title = "Changement de semaine"                         
content.body = "Nous sommes en semaine \(notificationSemaineAB())"     
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default                   

var dateComponent = DateComponents()
dateComponent.weekday = 2
dateComponent.hour = 11

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponent, repeats: true)

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "semaineAB", content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
```

For this one, I would like for each week, the text of notification tell me if we are in a even week or odd week. But in output, I have always the same text.

Comment: You can create a new notification with the new text, and remove the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the old notification with this code

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers:["semaineAB"])
```

And after that, you can reuse your code to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom class that extends UNMutableNotificationContent. That will determine the content of the notification based on the even/odd week. Then you can use another class to instantiate the notification request usign a method of the class of type UNMutableNotificationContent.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a separate class to handle all notification functions

- First Create a function which takes a string in your Notification Class
- Then use a bool value to check between even and odd week in your ViewController
- And also a function to put the logic for even/odd week

In Notifications.swift

```
class Notifications: NSObjcet, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

func weekTrigger(bodyText: String) {

let content = UNMutableNotificationContent() 

content.body = bodyText

let request = .......// 
}
```

Now in your ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var aBoolToCheckBtwnEvenOrOddWeek: Bool  //you can set an initial value

let notificationManager = Notifications()

}
```

Somewhere in VC where you see fit add the logic to check between even and odd week

```
func someFunction() {

if aBoolToCheckBtwnEvenOrOddWeek == true {   // which means even in my case

notificationManager.weekTrigger(bodyText: evenWeekString) // call the function 

} else {

notificationManager.weekTrigger(bodyText: oddWeekString)

}
}
```

Now add this function wherever you want in your ViewController!

Happy Coding :]